# command which creates a variable number of spaces

Tags: macros, arithmetic

Basically my problem is that I want to treat the argument to a command as a number (and perform arithmetic operations on it), but I can only get it to be treated as a string.
In particular, I want my command to insert a variable number of spaces, depending on the argument. I've tried this

```
\newcommand{\spc}[1]{\-\hspace{.5 * #1 cm}}
```

which of course does not work, but also

```
\newcommand{\spc}[1]{ \foreach \x in {0, \dots, #1} {\hspace{.5 cm}}}
```

which also does not work. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed your `*` to a `\dimexpr`.  By doing so, `#1 cm` is evaluated as a length, and *then* multiplied by `.5`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\spc}[1]{\-\hspace{.5 \dimexpr#1 cm}} 
\begin{document}
Testing\spc{1}Testing

Testing\spc{2}Testing

Testing\spc{5}Testing
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

TeX syntax allows something like `<number>\dimen` which performs the multiplication. You can try:

```
\newdimen\spcdimen \spcdimen=.5cm
\def\spc#1{\hskip #1\spcdimen \relax}

Testing\spc{1}Testing

Testing\spc{2}Testing

Testing\spc{5}Testing

\bye
```